# Passing square index instead of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I started building a Tic Tac Toe game using factory functions and modules and IIFE'S (as a requirment of the task) but I got tangled up in the logic of win conditions.

To put it short, I stored all the winning indexes of the table in a nested array, but now I can't grasp how to check these conditions on the actual table, I tried looping through the arrays and the array elements but it didn't work as intended.

The code:

```
const populateSquares = (squareIndex) => {
    allBoardSquares.forEach((square) => {
        square.addEventListener('click', () => {
            gameFlow.playMatch();
            setSquares(squareIndex, gameFlow.currentPlayer());
            if (gameFlow.checkWinner()) {
                SwapScreens.turnInfo.textContent = `${gameFlow.currentPlayer()} won this match!`;
                return
            };
            if (square.textContent == '') {
                square.textContent = gameFlow.currentPlayer();
            }
            if (match === 9) {
                SwapScreens.turnInfo.textContent = 'Tie!';
                return;
            }
        }, { once: true })
    })
}
populateSquares();
```

The win conditions:

```
const checkWinner = (squareIndex) => {
    const winIndexes = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];

    return winIndexes
        .filter((combination) => combination.includes(squareIndex))
        .some((possibleCombination) =>
            possibleCombination.every(
                (index) => GameBoard.getSquares(index) === currentPlayer()
            )
        );

};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work as intended"?

Comment: Yes, basically it just does not work, the text is not updated to show what player won, it just continues showing whose turn it is even if I have 3 O's in a row for example.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you `.filter((combination) => combination.includes(squareIndex))`? and if you do, why don't you pass it as argument in the function call?

Other than that, I think your code works once you remove that condition.

```js
var position = [
  'x', ' ', ' ', 
  ' ', 'x', 'x', 
  ' ', 'x', 'x'
];
var GameBoard = {
  getSquares : (index) => position[index]
}

var currentPlayer = () => 'x'
  
const checkWinner = () => {
  const winIndexes = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  return winIndexes
    .some((possibleCombination) =>
      possibleCombination.every(
        (index) => GameBoard.getSquares(index) === currentPlayer()
      )
    );

};

console.log(checkWinner(2))
```